# Iterating each character in a string using Python

Tags: python, string, iteration

How can I *iterate* over a string in Python (get each character from the string, one at a time, each time through a loop)?

Answer (score 515, accepted):

As Johannes pointed out,

```
for c in "string":
    #do something with c
```

You can iterate pretty much anything in python using the `for loop` construct,

for example, `open("file.txt")` returns a file object (and opens the file), iterating over it iterates over lines in that file

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        # do something with line
```

If that seems like magic, well it kinda is, but the idea behind it is really simple.

There's a simple iterator protocol that can be applied to any kind of object to make the `for` loop work on it.

Simply implement an iterator that defines a `next()` method, and implement an `__iter__` method on a class to make it iterable. (the `__iter__` of course, should return an iterator object, that is, an object that defines `next()`)

[See official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)

Comment: As a note, reversed iteration is archived with: for c in reversed("string")

Comment: From which part of the documentation do you know that a string is a iterator type?

Comment: dir() a string..you with see  __iter__  attribute.

Answer (score 346):

If you need access to the index as you iterate through the string, use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> for i, c in enumerate('test'):
...     print i, c
... 
0 t
1 e
2 s
3 t
```

Comment: Pro tip: it starts from zero. If you need to start it from one: `1 t`, `2 e`, `3 s`, `4 t` use the parameter "start": `for i, c in enumerate('test', start=1)`

Answer (score 95):

Even easier:

```
for c in "test":
    print c
```

Comment: I'm a newbie in Python. For some reason, this doesn't compile in my environment, and I had to put c in brackets to make it work:

`for c in "test":
    print (c)`

Why?

Comment: @MauroVanetti that's almost certainly because you're using Python 3 and when I answered the question there was AFAIK only Python 2.

Answer (score 40):

Just to make a more comprehensive answer, the C way of iterating over a string can apply in Python, if you really wanna force a square peg into a round hole.

```
i = 0
while i < len(str):
    print str[i]
    i += 1
```

But then again, why do that when strings are inherently iterable?

```
for i in str:
    print i
```

Comment: Instead of your first while loop, you can do:

for i in range(len(str)):
    print(str[i])

Which in my opinion is better than having to manage the counter on your own. Even better is marcog's answer using enumerate.

Comment: This may be based on just having used C for so long, but I almost always end up using this C-ish method.  For instance, I have a file with some 4-digit numbers scattered about, all of which start with 0.  So I need to find a "0" and grab it and the next 3 characters, and move on without duplicating the number if there's another 0 following it.  None of the "for c in str" or "for i,c in enumerate(str)" methods work because I need control of the index.
I'm sure a regular expression would be much better, though.

Comment: `for i in range(len(...))` is evil. In python 2.x, `range()` creates a list, so for a very long length you may end up allocating a very large block of memory. At the very least use `xrange()` in those cases. Also, repeated indexing of the same string is much slower than iterating directly over the string. If you need the index, use `enumerate()`.

Answer (score 7):

Well you can also do something interesting like this and do your job by using for loop

```
#suppose you have variable name
name = "Mr.Suryaa"
for index in range ( len ( name ) ):
    print ( name[index] ) #just like c and c++
```

Answer is

M r . S u r y a a

However since range() create a list of the values which is sequence thus you can directly use the name

```
for e in name:
    print(e)
```

This also produces the same result and also looks better and works with any sequence like list, tuple, and dictionary.

We have used tow Built in Functions ( BIFs in Python Community )

1) range() - range() BIF is used to create indexes 
   Example

```
for i in range ( 5 ) :
can produce 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4
```

2) len() - len() BIF is used to find out the length of given string

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to use a more functional approach to iterating over a string (perhaps to transform it somehow), you can split the string into characters, apply a function to each one, then join the resulting list of characters back into a string.

A string is inherently a list of characters, hence 'map' will iterate over the string - as second argument - applying the function - the first argument - to each one.

For example, here I use a simple lambda approach since all I want to do is a trivial modification to the character: here, to increment each character value:

```
>>> ''.join(map(lambda x: chr(ord(x)+1), "HAL"))
'IBM'
```

or more generally:

```
>>> ''.join(map(my_function, my_string))
```

where my_function takes a char value and returns a char value.

Answer (score 3):

Several answers here use `range`.   `xrange` is generally better as it returns a generator, rather than a fully-instantiated list.  Where memory and or iterables of widely-varying lengths can be an issue, `xrange` is superior.

Comment: note that this only applies to Python 2 which is hopefully a shrinking minority now

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the following:

```
txt = "Hello World!"
print (*txt, sep='\n')
```

This does not use loops but internally print statement takes care of it.

`*` unpacks the string into a list and sends it to the print statement

`sep='\n'` will ensure that the next char is printed on a new line

The output will be:

```
H
e
l
l
o
 
W
o
r
l
d
!
```

If you do need a loop statement, then as others have mentioned, you can use a for loop like this:

```
for x in txt: print (x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ever run in a situation where you need to `get the next char of the word using __next__()`, remember to create a `string_iterator` and iterate over it and not the `original string (it does not have the __next__() method)`

***In this example, when I find a char = `[` I keep looking into the next word while I don't find `]`, so I need to use __next__***

here a for loop over the string wouldn't help

```
myString = "'string' 4 '['RP0', 'LC0']' '[3, 4]' '[3, '4']'"
processedInput = ""
word_iterator = myString.__iter__()
for idx, char in enumerate(word_iterator):
    if char == "'":
        continue

    processedInput+=char

    if char == '[':
        next_char=word_iterator.__next__()
        while(next_char != "]"):
          processedInput+=next_char
          next_char=word_iterator.__next__()
        else:
          processedInput+=next_char
```