# Using **kwargs in alternating letter exercise

Tags: python

Hello I was wondering why using **kwargs is not working in this example. I was following the answer as given in  [Alternating letter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50049309/alternating-letter-in-python#comment87114737_50049309)

```py
def myfunc(**kwargs):
    return "".join(w.upper() if i%2 else w.lower() for i,w in enumerate(kwargs))
```

I have tried calling the function as myfunc("skyscraper") but get the error:

```py
TypeError: myfunc() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Its probably something simple but not obvious to me. In the exercise says I am not allowed to use print statements and the function as to return a string 
Thanks

Comment: `**argumentname` gives your function all unmatched arguments that were passed by keyword as a dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: you need to define a argument and use the name fo the argument to access the value. see my answer @yong_m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to pass a keyword argument to the function e.g. `myfunc(arg="skyscraper")`, and then use the name of the keyword argument in the function to extract out the value.

For example

```
def myfunc(**kwargs):
    #arg is the name of the argument, you extract the value from the kwargs dictionary
    return "".join(w.upper() if i%2 else w.lower() for i,w in enumerate(kwargs['arg']))

#Call myfunc using kwargs
print(myfunc(arg="skyscraper"))
```

The output will be

```
sKyScRaPeR
```

Answer (score 0):

**kwargs deals with keyword arguments.
try using:

```
myfunc(somekeyword="skyscraper")
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I am not sure though how could I change the function I've define to include this keyword I have tried defining inisde the function ``` python result = "".join(w.upper() if i%2 else w.lower() for i,w in enumerate(kwargs))``` and return result but that has not work.

Comment: @yong_m: you need to change the call, not the function itself