# how to make the function return ascii values of every character from the given string

Tags: python-3.x

Need to make a function that takes in a string and returns the ascii values for each letter in the string in a form of (103, 104, 105, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just can't get the ASCII values: what you want is the  `ord` function https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord

This actually gives you the unicode code Point - but that's equivalent in the ASCII range (which is up to 0xFF iirc)

Comment: I tried using the ord function but since it can only take in one character at a time it stumped me since the test code runs it with a string longer that one character

Comment: Ah well you need to iterate over your string so that you get each character. See for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538346/iterating-each-character-in-a-string-using-python

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) function for that

```
In [12]: ord('g')                                                               
Out[12]: 103

In [13]: ord('h')                                                               
Out[13]: 104

In [14]: ord('i')                                                               
Out[14]: 105
```

As an extra tidbit, use the [chr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) function to convert the ascii value to letter

```
In [15]: chr(103)                                                               
Out[15]: 'g'

In [16]: chr(104)                                                               
Out[16]: 'h'

In [17]: chr(105)                                                               
Out[17]: 'i'
```

And as you can guess.

```
In [18]: chr(ord('g')) == 'g'                                                   
Out[18]: True
```

To get ascii values for all characters of a string, just run a for loop over all characters

```
s = 'helloworld'

for c in s:
    print(ord(c))                                                                      
104
101
108
108
111
119
111
114
108
100
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the `ord()` function in python.

One line solution:

```
string = "ThisIsString!"
[ord(c)] for c in string]
```

Using `for` loop

```
asciis = []

for c in string:
    asciis.append(ord(c))

print(asciis)
```

> [84, 104, 105, 115, 73, 115, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 33]