# basic question about finding all indices of an occurrences in a string

Tags: python

i am in the first weeks of learning how to code in python and i need some feedback on a simple piece of code I have written

Objective: find and print all indices of "e" in a string

the code i have written

```
sentence = "celebrate"

for i in sentence:
    if i == "e":
        indexed_sentence = sentence.index("e")
        print(indexed_sentence)
```

I would like the code to print
1,3,8

Comment: use `enumerate`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4547728/3337070

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.index` method will return the index of the *first* occurrence of the character(s) you are searching for.  This means you will always see `1` for your code.  A better method is to use the built-in function `enumerate` as @Rakesh suggested.

```
sentence = "celebrate"

for ix, c in enumerate(sentence):
    if c=="e":
        print(ix)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over the string and matching the character you want correctly. When you found the match, you are just running `indexed_sentence = sentence.index("e")` which would give same answer everytime. You can modify your loop so that you know the index of the match as well using `enumerate`.

```
sentence = "celebrate"

for i, c in enumerate(sentence):
    if c == "e":
        print(i)
```